# Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to verify a few of my answers and get help on a few others.
Let $ (X,\preceq) $ be a partially ordered set and $A \subseteq X. $

> 1. Min$A$ exists and $ (A,\preceq) $ is totally ordered $\Longrightarrow  (A,\preceq) $ is well ordered.

False because in $\mathbb R $ with the usual order if $ A =\{x \geq 0\}$  has a minimum but not every subset of $ A $ has a minimum?

> 1. $ (A,\preceq) $ is totally ordered and $ A $ is finite and is well ordered.

True?

> 1. $ (F,\preceq) $ is totally ordered for each finite subset F of $X$ $ \Rightarrow (X,\preceq) $ is totally ordered.

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct, $(A, \le)$ is not well-ordered.
2. This is correct. You can prove this using the Pigeon Hole principle: Suppose $x_1 > x_2 > \cdots$ is an infinite descending sequence. Then there are $i,j$ with $i < j$ such that $x_i = x_j$. This implies... can you take it from here?
3. This is also correct. To prove this, consider each property (transitivity, totality) in turn, and notice that involves at most three elements. In fact, a stronger statement is correct: $(X,\preceq)$ is totally ordered iff every subset $F \subseteq X$ with at most three elements is totally-ordered. Also note that reflexivity follows from totality.